# Semantic-ui vs Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, semantic-ui

Which is the best one to use and if possible, please provide the difference(s) and advantages of these two.

[Semantic-ui](http://semantic-ui.com/) vs [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)
I am trying to build my UI and really confused as what to use.

Please suggest me the best one and if possible with examples.

Answer (score 65):

I think that we can't see the differences between [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) and [Semantic-UI](https://github.com/semantic-org/semantic-ui/) right now, Semantic-ui is new, so we have to let the time decide :)

**My opinion:** Semantic-UI design is better than Bootstrap and more clean, easy to use, strict coding, useful components, lightweight. I see the future of Frameworks in Semantic-UI, so I will contribute and hope the best for it, but I will not use it for big projects that depend on a huge feedbacks and supports!

Comment: I really like your opinion, especially on "will not use it for big projects that depends on a huge feedbacks and supports". Because I was just about to jump ship.

Comment: 2 years ago, Semantic UI seemed to be more lightweight than Bootstrap. But now, let have a look...

Comment: Well i cant agree, im going to use semantic-ui for the first time, and will be in a big project, for what i see, im quite sure that will handle quite well.

Answer (score 31):

If you don't mind, I add Foundation by Zurb in the topic (the only true valid alternative to Bootstrap at the moment).

I just checked the project/framework SemUI and it's pretty awesome. The idea of building your pages in a strict semantic way is obviously good, moreover the design is stunning in my opinion and there are a lot of components and settings to use and to choose from the set.

Another thing that I noticed is the package, very well organized, every component if you want has its own stylesheet and script-file, therefore you'll be able to load only what you need, even because the package is quite heavy if you include everything in a single page.

For a pre-release I admit that I'm considering to build my next web-app with such framework, but I got some perplexities:

- is that mobile-first like Bootstrap or Foundation? from what I'm able to see, it doesn't look so;
- Bootstrap has two valid and well-known contributors and Foundation got Zurb behind, what about SemanticUI? this is a pre-release, are we gonna see other releases?

because of such perplexities I think to avoid to use it for a business/commercial project at the moment, maybe in a very near future, but if you're planning to use it for your own personal web-app (like mine), I think it's a pretty good choice.

Then if you wanna fallback to Bootstrap for any reason, I think it's not that painful (many of Semantic components seem based on Bootstrap).

Comment: Its worth noting that SemUI uses presentational class names just like Foundation and Bootstrap despite having semantic in its name. I agree that the class names are less abstract but they are presentational in the same way. If you are interested Foundation 3/4 allows you to use Sass Mixins to create truly semantic html/css. You can set an id based on the "content" and then apply Foundation Sass Mixins to that id in your Sass/Scss.

Comment: The component design of semanticUI is eye catching. But semanticUI is behind bootstrap in the case of browser compatibility. Bootstrap compatible with IE 7+, but semanticUI compatible only IE 9+

Comment: @McLosysCreative To be honest, that could be seen more as a drawback for Bootstrap. I agree that all HTML/CSS frameworks should have a fair amount of browser compatibility, but only within reason. At this point, IE7 is 8 years old, and is 4 major versions behind. Even Google doesn't officially support it anymore. (they only officially support the latest 3 versions of the top 5 browsers) With that in mind, it seems a wasted effort (and extra code) to support that far back.

Answer (score -18):

Semantic UI doesn't really address mobile or responsive views like Bootstrap and Foundation do. It's more like a collection of prepackaged UI elements that work pretty well together with semantic markup that's superior to Bootstrap/Foundation. But the biggest drawback right now is that it's not mobile-centric.  So if you want a well styled site, use Semantic-UI.

Comment: Semantic-UI isn't responsive?

Comment: In whole project they have not used px unit while they are using em everywhere !!!

Comment: Semantic UI is definitely responsive. You should update your answer otherwise it's incorrect.

Comment: This answer is definitely outdated. Semantic IS responsive.

Comment: Semantic-UI is born for responsive.

Comment: semantic-ui eat bootstrap